# find value by tag name in xml

Tags: .net, xml, c#-2.0

How can I find value by tag name in xml file?  using C#.net 2.0

There are just 10 distinct nodes in my xmldocument.

I dont want to write xpath. I think there is an auto find property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem with this scneirao:

XmlNodeList nl = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("CustomerID"); sb.Append(nl[0].InnerXml);

Answer (score 0):

Can't remember the exact syntax, but write an Xpath query and then use `XPathNavigator.Select` to find it.

Edit: Just remember, I think it's something like `//@tagname`, so if you do `XPathNavigator.Select("//@tagname")` I think it would work. Assuming that with tag you mean an attribute, if you're looking for elements it should just be `//tagname`.

Answer (score 0):

see this complete function get node value as well as attribute value from xml file...

```
public string GetXmlNodeValue(string xmlfilePath, string TagName, string Attribute)
{
    XmlDocument objXML = new XmlDocument();
    bool IsNodeValuefound = false;
    string Value = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(xmlfilePath))
        {
            objXML.Load(xmlfilePath);

            XmlNode xNode = objXML.DocumentElement.FirstChild;
            while (xNode != null)
            {
                if (string.Compare(xNode.Name, TagName, true) == 0)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Attribute))
                    {
                        if (xNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem(Attribute) != null)
                        {
                            IsNodeValuefound = true;
                            Value = xNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem(Attribute).Value;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        IsNodeValuefound = true;
                        Value = xNode.InnerText.Trim();
                    }
                }
                xNode = xNode.NextSibling;
            }
        }
        if (IsNodeValuefound)
            return Value;
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }
    catch (XmlException xmlEx)
    {
        throw xmlEx;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        objXML = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but I dont want to use lots of code lines. Just like GetElementByID and reaching its value

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(someRawData);
XmlNodeList yourNodes = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("YourTagName");
```

Then you can iterate through yourNodes and takes the values.

Answer (score 0):

Firt, get XmlDocument by this code:

```
XmlDocument infodoc = new XmlDocument();
infodoc.LoadXml(xmlString);
```

In case the your tag look like:

```
<directory value="D:/BACKUPS"></directory>
```

get value of 'directory' tag by following:

```
var directory = infodoc.GetElementsByTagName("directory")[0].Attributes["value"].Value;
```

In case the your tag look like:

```
<directory>D:/BACKUPS</directory>
```

get value of 'directory' tag by following:

```
var directory = infodoc.GetElementsByTagName("directory")[0].InnerXml;
```